# VBA For-Next loop gets slower after 255 iterations

Tags: vba

I'm trying to call excel's FORECAST.ETS from VBA and I have a for loop which works well for the first 255 iterations and dramatically gets slower from the 256th.
I would be glad if someone can help me. I would also be happy about a better and faster solution.

```
Public Sub CreateDatabase()
Application.Calculation = XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i as Long
    For i = 1 To 336
        With Worksheets("Sheet1")
            .Range("AHV" & i + 1 & ":AIS" & i + 1).Formula = "=IFERROR(FORECAST.ETS(Sheet1!AHV$1,Sheet1!$B" & i + 1 & ":$AHU" & i + 1 & ",Sheet1!$B$1:$AHU$1,1),0)"
        End With
        Application.StatusBar = Format(Round(100 * i / 336, 2), "0.00") & "% - " & i * 24 & " of " & 336 * 24 & " items created"
    Next 
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you iterate backwards? (I don't know if it helps but inserting at the beginning of a chain might not get slower with each - when inserting at the end does.)

Comment: Have you tried removing the loop and using `.Range("AHV2:AIS337").Formula = "=IFERROR(FORECAST.ETS(Sheet1!AHV$1,Sheet1!$B2:$AHU337,Sheet1!$B$1:$AHU$1,1),0)"`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook You meant `Sheet1!$B2:$AHU2`.

Comment: @GSerg.   Thanks, yes I did.... still early morning. :)

Comment: Try turning off the status bar - this is sometimes a performance-killer as well - especially with those calculations

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, thank you for the solution but it lasts 127 secs as my loop lasted before.

Comment: @MartinPacker, when I iterate backwards, up to i value 256, it works slow then gets faster :)))

Comment: Perhaps insert the second half forwards, then the first half backwards. Odd but might get you out of trouble - if 336 really is the count. i.e. less than twice 255.

Comment: @BülentÇakar Given that you have disabled calculations, it cannot take 127 seconds, it will be instant. When you switch the calculations back on, then it probably takes 127 seconds. Do you also have a Worksheet_Change handler by any chance?

Comment: @GSerg I am totally agreed that it should be instant. Actually it works so up to 256th iteration.  the last 30 iterations take 120 smthg secs. my problem is, when i change loop counter 1 to 255, then it works like a charm but if the counter starts from 256, loop for 30 iterations takes about 120 secs.

Comment: @BülentÇakar You were supposed to [remove the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69401818/vba-for-next-loop-gets-slower-after-255-iterations?noredirect=1#comment122667499_69401818) completely.